# How to return to the previously selected index on index change event

Tags: .net, winforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a issue leading on from this question: [How can I handle ComboBox selected index changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782313/how-can-i-handle-combobox-selected-index-changing) The first comment of the answer to the question basically asks the same as what I'm asking here.

It describes how to catch an index change event. This works fine however I've got an error provider waiting on this event that effectively makes certain fields compulsory. If it equates to true (or in other words a compulsory field is empty) it exits out of the sub.

This works fine; the data remains the same and the compulsory fields are highlighted however the problems occurs from the fact that the selected index has already changed. In other words you're seeing the data from the original index but the actual highlighted index within the combo-box has already changed. The event's *ChangedIndex*, it fires when an index has been changed.

Is there anyway I can re-select the previous index and/or cancel the transition to the new index? Is there a event like ChangingIndex in a similar manor to what the DeletingRecord is to the RecordDeleted event?

EDIT- I'm using a ListBox not a ComboBox which doesn't have the SelectedIndexChanging event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `ListBox` from the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, you can add an event handler for `ListBox.SelectionChanged`:

`listBox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(listBox_SelectionChanged);`

do a check if your error provider has a `true` value, if so, I believe this should work (I have similar logic on `ComboBox` controls using the same event):

You can add this to the event handler:

```
//Check if error provider returned true
if(hasError)
{
    //Cast the sender object as ListBox
    ListBox listbox = (ListBox)sender;

    //If there was already something selected before, set it as the SelectedItem
    if(e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
    }
}
```

Of course, this might not work if you're able to select multiple items.

**EDIT**: Since it seems like you're using the `ListBox` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (which doesn't have the `SelectionChanged` event), you could try having a property in your code behind that represents the currently selected Index for the `ListBox`

Within your `SelectedIndexChanged` event, check the condition from your Error Provider.  If it has an error, return the Item that is saved to your property, otherwise update the value to the newly selected item.

Not the most elegant solution, but it should work.

```
int _CurrentSelectedIndex = -1; //variable to keep track of the SelectedIndex initialized to default value (-1)

//Add event listener to the ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged event
ListBox listBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(list_SelectedIndexChanged);


    //Event handler implementation
    void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cast the sender object as ListBox
        ListBox listbox = (ListBox)sender;

        //validation function detected an error
        if(!passedValidation)
        {
            listBox.SelectedIndex = _CurrentSelectedIndex; //revert to the previously selected item
        }

        //Passed validation - update variable to keep track of the SelectedIndex
        else
        {
            _CurrentSelectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried to put this into my code however it seems that sysargs doesn't have the 'RemovedItems' argument. I'm working from within a SelectedIndexChanged event and in VB.net. Not sure if that has something to do with it?

Comment: There's only a few arguments I can use, none do what I need.

Comment: @Noodlemanny It sounds like you're using the `ListBox` in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and not the one in `System.Windows.Controls` since you're using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and not the `SelectionChanged` event.  Do you have to use the ListBox in `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: @Noodlemanny  I updated my answer to include a potential solution using the `ListBox` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about the issue I've come up with a simple solution. I simply created a new variable called 'ListBoxIndex' and gave it the default start index. When all the compulsory fields are filled and the validation function comes through true I set the value of ListBoxIndex to listBox.SelectedIndex. When the validation comes back false I simply reset the listBox.SelectedIndex to the ListBoxIndex value thereby putting it back to the previous index.

Comment: Glad you got it to work! But isn't this the same solution I have above (with the only change being that I did it within an event on `ListBox` like you were attempting to in the OP)? :p

Comment: To be fair, I didn't really understand your solution let alone get it to work :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: Essentially it's what you described above - I added an event handler on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the `ListBox` and if the validation function returns `false` (represented by the `!passedValidation` boolean variable), it sets the `SelectedIndex` to the index saved in the `_CurrentSelectedIndex` variable.  If it passed validation, then update the value in the `_CurrentSelectedIndex` to the value it was changed to.  What part was hard to follow?  I updated it a bit, but let me know if I should add more details to help anyone in the future that has a similar issue

Comment: Ah, I think my main issue was I was unsure of the nature of the _CurrentSelectedIndex. I was unclear if it was a function, variable etc. Since you've made it clearer now I guess I can accept your answer.