# vb.net Subclassing ComboBox - trying to create a SelectedIndexChanging event that can be cancelled

Tags: vb.net, combobox, event-handling, subclass, selectedindexchanged

I'm currently trying to implement the second response from this thread [How can I handle ComboBox selected index changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782313/how-can-i-handle-combobox-selected-index-changing/791421#791421) in vb (the response that suggests subclassing ComboBox to introduce new SelectedIndexChangingEvent).  The event handler

```
Private Sub MyComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles MyComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanging
        MsgBox("Changing")
End Sub
```

never gets hit.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the way I'm initializing the selectedIndexChanging (lowercase first letter) variable.  Any thoughts?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyComboBox
    Inherits ComboBox

    Public Event SelectedIndexChanging as CancelEventHandler
    Public LastAcceptedSelectedIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        LastAcceptedSelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanging(e As CancelEventArgs)
        Dim selectedIndexChanging as CancelEventHandler = SelectedIndexChanging
        If Not SelectedIndexChanging Is Nothing Then
            selectedIndexChanging(Me, e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If LastAcceptedSelectedIndex <> SelectedIndex Then
            Dim cancelEventArgs = New CancelEventArgs
            OnSelectedIndexChanging(cancelEventArgs)
            If Not cancelEventArgs.Cancel Then
                LastAcceptedSelectedIndex = SelectedIndex
                MyBase.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)
            Else 
                SelectedIndex = LastAcceptedSelectedIndex
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

VB handles event declaration a bit different than C#.  The VB `RaiseEvent` keyword effectively generates code you attempted to translate for the `OnSelectedIndexChanging' method.

The correct VB implementation would be:

```
 Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanging(e As CancelEventArgs)
      RaiseEvent SelectedIndexChanging(Me, e)
 End Sub
```

You could follow the original pattern, by using the hidden variable VB creates that is the real `CancelEventHandler` variable.  These hidden variables follow the naming pattern of eventName**Event**.  So the real `CancelEventHandler` variable is named: SelectedIndexChangingEvent.

```
 Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanging(e As CancelEventArgs)
      Dim selectedIndexChanging As CancelEventHandler = Me.SelectedIndexChangingEvent

      If Not selectedIndexChanging Is Nothing Then
            selectedIndexChanging(Me, e)
      End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that token of knowledge TnTinMn.  Best regards to you.